# What is used the most while telling time in AmE?

Tags: word-usage, american-english

In tellling-time constructions like the following:

> It's half past ten.
>
> It's a quarter to two.

What is commmonly used in AmE before *past* and *to*?

My guess is that only *half*, *a quarter* and numbers 0 through 29 [possibly followed by *minute(s)*] are used.

How far off from the actual American usage am I?

Comment: I think no Yank would use *zero* or *one* in such constructions, and to-the-minute precision is rather alien to the construction with "to," so only multiples of five are likely to to be involved in that. (Where to-the-minute precision is desired, we usually just go with the full "it's eight fifty-six" pattern.) Oh, and we seldom bother to utter the word "minutes" in any of these constructions; maybe "one minute past three" and possibly "two minutes past three" but beyond that just the number without the unit.

Comment: If it were 3:01 I would say 'three oh one'

Comment: My grandmother and aunt were fond of saying, eg, "It's ten of."  (They'd leave you to guess the hour.)  But I don't recall hearing that construction in years.  With digital everything most of the "past" and "to" notations have become archaic.